# Create a dynamic XML elements with Lxml

Tags: python, xml, loops, nested, lxml

I've had some help to generate my XML using the lxml library and that has been very useful and I've been able to extend it to solve most of my issues. There is one use case which I'm struggling with. I've tried a suggestion but still struggling

A simple representation of my dataset below

```
ID,Currency,Notional,Maturity,Type
ID1,,,,2018-06-01,
ID1-L1,EUR,100,,,Bond
ID1-L2,JPY,110,,A
ID1-L2,CNY,115,,B
ID2,,,,2018-06-01,
ID2-L1,EUR,100,,,Stock
ID2-L2,JPY,110,,C
ID2-L2,JPY,110,,D
```

Essentially I have two records here ID-1 and ID2. ID-L1, ID-L2 etc are child elements of ID1 and there will be several instances of ID-L2. My problem is I need to identify all occurrences of ID-L2  etc and create a new element for each occurrence and then move to the next record ID2 and repeat. So in effect my results will look something like this.

```
<tradeRequests>
    <ids>
    <mainid>ID1</mainid>
            <element>
                <maturityDate>2018-06-01</maturityDate>
            </element>
                <cffixed>
                    <element>
                        <id>ID-L1</id>
                        <currency>EUR</currency>
                    </element>
                </cffixed>
                <cffloat>
                    <element>
                        <id>ID1-L2</id>
                        <currency>JPY</currency>
                    </element>
                    <element>
                        <id>ID1-L2</id>
                        <currency>CNY</currency>
                    </element>
                </cffloat>
        </ids>
</tradeRequests>
```

So this is a snippet of code I've used but I've hardcoded the values instead of referencing the content from a file for this example.

```
import csv
import lxml.etree
from lxml.builder import E

with open('tc.csv', 'r') as fb:
         results = E.tradeRequests(*(
             E.ids(
                 E.mainid('id'),
                 E.element(
                     E.MaturityDate('maturity'),
                     E.cffixed(
                         E.element(
                             E.id('id'),
                             E.currency('currency'),
                            ),
                        ),
                    E.cffloat(
                        E.element(
                            E.id('id'),
                            E.currency('id'),
                            ) #for r in ids2_rows,
                        ),
                     ),
    )for row in csv.DictReader(fb))
 )
print(lxml.etree.tostring(results, pretty_print=True))
```

My issue is independently I can find a way of identifying the rows that are ID-L2 but just not sure how I can get the for loop to use it. This really is the missing jigsaw so help appreciated as always.

Comment: Build the base XML with `etree.XML` or `etree.fromstring`.  The locate where you want to add the next element with xpath.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion @shrewmouse. In the end, the method below from nosklo resolved the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This approach uses `itertools.groupby` to group the data by ID before generating the elements. That way a single `mainid` can be added for each element.

```
import itertools
import csv
import lxml.etree
from lxml.builder import E

with open('tc.csv', 'r') as fb:
    cf = csv.DictReader(fb)
    def groupkey(row):
        return row['ID'].split('-')[0] # group by first part of ID

    result_ids = E.ids()
    result = E.tradeRequests(result_ids)

    for main_id, rows in itertools.groupby(cf, key=groupkey):
        rows = list(rows)
        result_ids.extend([
            E.mainid(main_id),
            E.element(E.maturityDate(rows[0]['Type'])),
            E.cffixed(E.element(E.id(rows[1]['ID']), E.currency(rows[1]['Currency']))),
            E.cffloat(*(E.element(E.id(r['ID']), E.currency(r['Currency']))
                for r in rows[2:])),
        ])
print(lxml.etree.tostring(result, pretty_print=True))
```

The results, when running with the csv you provided in the question:

```
<tradeRequests>
  <ids>
    <mainid>ID1</mainid>
    <element>
      <maturityDate>2018-06-01</maturityDate>
    </element>
    <cffixed>
      <element>
        <id>ID1-L1</id>
        <currency>EUR</currency>
      </element>
    </cffixed>
    <cffloat>
      <element>
        <id>ID1-L2</id>
        <currency>JPY</currency>
      </element>
      <element>
        <id>ID1-L2</id>
        <currency>CNY</currency>
      </element>
    </cffloat>
    <mainid>ID2</mainid>
    <element>
      <maturityDate>2018-06-01</maturityDate>
    </element>
    <cffixed>
      <element>
        <id>ID2-L1</id>
        <currency>EUR</currency>
      </element>
    </cffixed>
    <cffloat>
      <element>
        <id>ID2-L2</id>
        <currency>JPY</currency>
      </element>
      <element>
        <id>ID2-L2</id>
        <currency>JPY</currency>
      </element>
    </cffloat>
  </ids>
</tradeRequests>
```

Comment: This is great @Nosklo, looks good. I would never have worked this out. Thanks for saving my butt.